# Is there any limit for concurrent extranet domain users in a Sitecore website?

Tags: security, authentication

How many extranet users can login to a sitecore website at the same time? Is there any limitation for the number of concurrent logins?
NB: This question is not about sitecore users([Number of concurrent Sitecore Users](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9143/number-of-concurrent-sitecore-users)), its all about extranet users.

Comment: The license.xml file will show you the limits and this is basically on the client license and not on the development license.This is already answered in https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9143/number-of-concurrent-sitecore-users

Comment: You are referring to questions about Sitecore users. The question here is about extranet users - which is not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by login into Sitecore website as extranet users? Please specify more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No.

Not for Extranet users.

> If a Sitecore license restricts the number of concurrent users, that
>   restriction applies only to CMS users, not to visitors to or extranet
>   users on the published sites.

Source: [Visitors and Users in the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/visitors-and-users-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms)